# How to set permissions on registry keys from the command line?

Tags: windows, permissions, command-line-interface, windows-registry

There used to be the tool Regini.exe from the Windows 2000 Resource Kit to do this, but it is no longer supported by Microsoft. Reg.exe can't do it either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joe's post about SubInAcl is perfectly valid. I happen to prefer [SetACL](http://setacl.sourceforge.net/), which basically does the same things with a different command-line syntax. It's also available as an ActiveX control such that it's easy to call in scripts.

Comment: I find that SubInAcl orders ACLs incorrectly at times.

Answer (score 6):

[`SubInAcl`](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E8BA3E56-D8FE-4A91-93CF-ED6985E3927B) is your friend here.

Comment: I wonder when the "...is your friend" expression got started here. I've been using it for awhile now, and I'm seeing it in a lot more posts.

Comment: Think we need a new tag, is-your-friend, for those must-have utilities.